# Decoding character strings vectors in R

Tags: r, string, encoding, utf-8, ascii

Suppose you have an atomic vector containing encoded character strings:

```
string_encoding <- c("São Paulo", "Paraná")
```

Is there any way to decode every element in the vector, returning a vector of the same length with ASCII, ISO-8859-1 or other class of encoding?

The output should be:

```
expected_encoding <- c("Sao Paulo", "Parana")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `stringi`, you can do:

```
stri_trans_general(string_encoding, "Latin-ASCII")

[1] "Sao Paulo" "Parana"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option can be:

```
iconv(string_encoding, to='ASCII//TRANSLIT')
```

Output:

```
[1] "Sao Paulo" "Parana"
```